# Power BI. The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it, Microsoft Exchange

Tags: email, powerbi, connection, connector, microsoft-exchange

While joining my account to Power BI with the correct credentials I got this error:

[image]

Does my account need some more access on the Microsoft site?